# Need Help Refactoring a React Component

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, tailwind-css

Could someone help me refactor a component I'm building? I'm having the hardest time finding a way to animate the scrollRight. Any help or insight would be great!

https://jsfiddle.net/chrischilcoat/s9pqg2wL/7

This is the function I'm using to animate the position of the scrollRight position.

```
  const scrollRight = () => {
    pager.current.scrollLeft += pager.current.clientWidth;
    setButtonState();
  };
```

I just cant seem to find a simple solution for adding animation to the transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the scroll function with the behavior smooth:

```
const scrollRight = () => {
    pager.current.scroll({
        left: pager.current.scrollLeft + pager.current.clientWidth,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    setButtonState();
  };



const scrollLeft = () => {
    pager.current.scroll({
        left: pager.current.scrollLeft - pager.current.clientWidth,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    setButtonState();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for smooth scrolling? In that case add correspondent style to your component:

```
.scrollbar-hide{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: My only concern with this one is i want that scrollbar-hide utility to only do one thing. I guess an option could be making another class .scroll-smooth.